# Javascript to remove spaces from .value

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim

```
//loop thought all the sku field
$('.optionSku').each(function() {

    //if found field are empty
    if (jQuery.trim(this.value) == "") {

        //loop thought all the name field to copy to the empty field
        $('.optionName').each(function() {

            if ($(this).closest("tr").find(".optionSku").val() == "") {

                empty++;
                $(this).closest("tr").find(".optionSku").val($(this).val());
            }

        });
    }
})
```

How to remove space from this.value using JQuery?
I try to put `if (jQuery.trim(this.value) == "")`, but it cannot remove the inline space and removes the leading and trailing spaces only.

Comment: you could use 1)$(this).closest("tr").find(".optionSku").val($(this).val().trim()); or $(this).closest("tr").find(".optionSku").val($.trim($(this).val()));

Comment: Hi! do want remove all the spaces, even those who are between the words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.value =  this.value.trim(); 
//you need to assign the trimmed value back to it.
```

Note that [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) may not be available in IE < 9 version. So you can use:

```
this.value = $.trim(this.value);
```

Comment: .trim is not as compatible as $.trim

Comment: Can't disagree with that :) will change accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The `$.trim()` function removes all newlines, spaces (including non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the supplied string. If these whitespace characters occur in the middle of the string, they are preserved.
if you want to remove leading and trailing spaces use

```
//loop thought all the sku field
 $('.optionSku').each(function() {
    //if found field are empty
    if ($.trim(this.value)=="") {
       //loop thought all the name field to copy to the empty field
       $('.optionName').each(function() {
          if ($(this).closest("tr").find(".optionSku").val() == "") {
             empty++;
             $(this).closest("tr").find(".optionSku").val($(this).val());
          }
       });
    }
 });
```

if you want to inline spaces use

```
//loop thought all the sku field
 $('.optionSku').each(function() {
    //if found field are empty
    if (this.value.trim()=="") {
       //loop thought all the name field to copy to the empty field
       $('.optionName').each(function() {
          if ($(this).closest("tr").find(".optionSku").val() == "") {
             empty++;
             $(this).closest("tr").find(".optionSku").val($(this).val());
          }
       });
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how trim work in javascript.

```
var val = this.value.trim();
```

Comment: Already answered and they use jQuery so the more compatible $.trim is preferred

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(this.value.trim()==""){
    //code here
}
```

Comment: .trim is not as compatible as $.trim

Answer (score 0):

.replace(/ /g,'')
The g character means to repeat the search through the entire string.
If you want to match all whitespace, and not just the literal space character, use \s as well:

.replace(/\s/g,'')